# Parsing a JSON file and comparing semvers

Tags: php, json, semantic-versioning

I have a json file that looks roughly something like this.

```
{
   "foo" : {
      "name" : "bar", 
      "dev-master" : {}, 
      "3.0-dev" : {}, 
      "2.4" : {}, 
      "master" : {},
   }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a solution to parse and get the most resent semver tag. I tried as far as:

```
<?php 
$file = 'data.json'; 
$content = file_get_contents($file); 
$content = json_decode($content); 

$container = [];
foreach($content as $version){
  $container[$version] = $version; 
}

..
```

Now, assuming that `$container` contains all the tags, how do I get the most recent version would would be 2.4.

Getting the `2.4` is not the problem, but making a future-proof reliable way to find out which is the recent.

Comment: Will it always be before master? or near the end?

Comment: PHP has a version_compare function. But that sort of relies on the versions being in a format that it understands haha

Comment: @Darren I don't know. That is the real issue. I guess this question is more about sematic versioning than php/json

Comment: Well... does this project actually use something like http://semver.org/ ? Or another set of rules? Without knowing them, it's hard for us to help.

Comment: @rjdown Yes. It follows the semver rules

Comment: Then I think version_compare should work for you

Comment: @rjdown thanks, I would look at it now

Comment: You can use it within a sorting function (usort for example), then grab the first result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.  It uses the assumption that the most recent version number would be composed of only digits and decimal points.  You can update the regular expression to allow dashes, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'));
$container = [];
foreach($content as $name => $versions){
        $props   = get_object_vars($versions);
        $container[$name] = null;
        foreach (array_keys($props) as $versionName) {
                if (preg_match('/^[0-9\.]+$/',$versionName)) {
                        // Ensure if multiple versions are present the greatest 
value will be used
                        if (isset($container[$name])) {
                            $container[$name] = max($versionName,$container[$nam
e]);
                        } else {
                            $container[$name] = $versionName;
                        }
                }
        }
}
var_dump($container);
```

If no final version is found, the version name will be null.

Comment: *"It uses the assumption ..."* That is what I am trying to avoid. If it is based on assumptions it will never be correct.

Comment: You need to define what the 'latest version' is somehow.  Is there a date/timestamp you could use?

Comment: Yes, there is a timestamp actually. It is just nested serveral levels down so, it's a bit hard to fetch and compare all

Comment: The **max** should ensure this works with semantic versioning.